# R CRAN Check - detritus in temp directory

Tags: r, cran

I'm getting a recurring NOTE on Debian CRAN checks (Debian only: 11 OK, 1 NOTE), it cannot be reproduced locally using docker interactively or via {rhub}.

```
* checking for detritus in the temp directory ... NOTE
Found the following files/directories:
  ‘calibre_4.99.5_tmp_tgaufday’ ‘calibre_4.99.5_tmp_uz2f_rsg’
```

The name of the files differ every time but they always start with `calibre` and there are always two of them. This is for the package {echarts4r}, the latest CRAN fail [here](https://win-builder.r-project.org/incoming_pretest/echarts4r_0.3.2_20200618_183103/Debian/00check.log).

**EDIT** this is called by creating a browser in the examples, ensure these are not run with `if(interactive())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out this issue appears when one starts a web browser from the `@examples`, in my case a shiny application, wrap them in `if(interactive())`, it was difficult to tell given the NOTE...

Comment: John, this should be added as a comment or in your original question

Comment: Thanks mister @JohnCoene!

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't matter, so far as I can tell.  That sort of 'detritus' won't show up when the package is rebuilt at CRAN.   On OS X one often sees a similar note due to leftover files from the attempts to go text --> LaTeX --> PDF.  Unless someone from the R dev team rejects your submission, ignore this.

Comment: It seems to me as well, it’s just I’ve never replied to the auto reject email: I guess it’s ok in this case.